# Sub-class casting for methods

Tags: java, class, interface, casting, abstract-class

OK, so I'll start this with an example:

Let's say we have an abstract class with an interface variable, which is initialized in the constructor. The abstract class itself has a getter for that variable, it's subclasses have implementations of the interface in the constructor.

Now, the problem I'm getting is that when trying to call the getter of any of the subclasses (which is only declared in the superclass, but it should use the variable declared in their constructors) it doesn't return the implementation, it returns the interface itself.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
    private final ExampleInterface exampleInterface;

    public AbstractClass(ExampleInterface exampleInterface) {
        this.exampleInterface = exampleInterface;
    }

    public ExampleInterface getExampleInterface() {
        return this.exampleInterface;
    }
}

public class AbstractClassSubclass extends AbstractClass {

    //Instead of the interface itself, I provide my constructor it's implementation
    public AbstractClassSubclass(ExampleInterfaceImplementation exampleInterfaceImpl) {
        super(exampleInterfaceImpl);
    }
}

public class TestClass {
    private void testMethod() {
        AbstractClassSubclass test = new AbstractClassSubclass(
                new ExampleInterfaceImplementation()
        );

        //Would return ExampleInterface, instead of ExampleInterfaceImplementation
        test.getExampleInterface();
    }
}
```

**Update**

I believe I have fixed this using type parameters.
I'm sure I have tried it before but had a few problems...

Now it works perfectly.

Comment: please provide some code to illustrate your description.

Comment: The code formatting is not broken. Just read the formatting instructions, or just select the code and press Ctrl k. Also, post a question.

Comment: I've updated it now, haha.